# Nodejs - FindOneAndUpdate method works but makes my website crash (using mongo) on events.js

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I want to delete an array index with an ID that I get from front-end. My code works fine and the elements are deleted, however the website crashes and I have to restart npm or check mongo's atlas to check the results. I'm really in the dark here.
Here's the error:

```
 events.js:167
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

    ReferenceError: errors is not defined
        at User.findOneAndUpdate (C:\repos\InventoryApp\routes\index.js:52:17)
        at C:\repos\InventoryApp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4851:16
        at process.nextTick (C:\repos\InventoryApp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2776:28)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
    Emitted 'error' event at:
        at C:\repos\InventoryApp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4853:13
        at process.nextTick (C:\repos\InventoryApp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2776:28)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
    [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

//all variables are set and I have done a push method with the same variables
User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { email : useremail },                  
        { $pull: { products: {
            _id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)
        }  } },
        (err) => {
             if (err) console.log('found errors');
                req.flash('success_msg', 'New record');

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)` was causing this issue.
By doing `_id : id` I mananged to make it work.